# Round number using a js funcion not keeping the first 0

Tags: javascript

I'm making a function to round the last number when more then 3 digits after comma, but when I got like :

18093941.000

I run the function and result is:

18,94

and it shroud be

18,094.

How I fix this

here what I have done :

```js
const round = num => Math.round(+('' + num).slice(0, 3) + '.' + ('' + num).slice(3, ('' + num).length));

function numberWithCommas(value) {
  let rounded = value.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
  // rounded now is 18,093,941
  const test1 = rounded.split(',')[0]; // 18
  const test2 = rounded.split(',')[1]; // 093
  const test3 = rounded.split(',')[2]; // 941
  //join test2 and test3 i got 093941
  //
  rounded = test1 + ',' + round(test2 + test3);
  // rounded now is 18,94
  // expected result is 18,094
  return rounded;
}

console.log(numberWithCommas(18093941.000));
```

Comment: So the outcome of `numberWithCommas(18093941)` should be `18,093,941`, right?

Comment: @nickzoum no, the outcume shoud be '18,094'

Comment: What is wrong with using `Math.round` function?

Comment: yes i know that but the final result shoud be 18,094 because is MWh

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL So do you always want to divide by 1000 and then round whatever is left?

Comment: @nickzoum i think that is what i need to do

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi the final expected result shoud be 18,094

Comment: @SalmanA better options are wellcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) and [`Number#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) after dividing with `1000`.

```js
function numberWithCommas(value) {
  return Math.round(value / 1E3).toLocaleString("en-US");
}

console.log(numberWithCommas(18093941));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that '093' convert to int by `+` operator and it would be '93'. So you need to store leading zero and add to the result

Try this one:

```js
const round = num => Math.round(+('' + num).slice(0, 3) + '.' + ('' + num).slice(3, ('' + num).length));

        function numberWithCommas(value) {
            let rounded = value.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '.');
            const test1 = rounded.split('.')[0];
            const test2 = rounded.split('.')[1];
            const test3 = rounded.split('.')[2];

            var num = test2 + test3;
            var zeros = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                if (num[i] == "0")
                    zeros += "0"
                else
                    break;
            }

            rounded = test1 + ',' + zeros + round(num);
            return rounded;
        }

        console.log(numberWithCommas(18093941.000));
```

Comment: that works too, i will keep in mind for next problems, tanks for your time to help